# Nested array in android

Tags: android, multidimensional-array

I want to make/handle nested array in android. My nested array will be similar to this.

```
[array name] = [1] = [1] = a
                     [2] = b
                     [3] = d
               [2] = [1] = a
                     [2] = b
                     [3] = d
               [3] = [1] = a
                     [2] = b
                     [3] = d
```

I tried to this with HashMap and ArrayList but I don't think that would work.. Is there any idea to work with such nested array??

Comment: Or, even better, a "jagged" (or "sparse") array

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
String[][] array = new String[intSize][intSize];
 // print array in rectangular form
 for (int r=0; r<array.length; r++) {
     for (int c=0; c<array[r].length; c++) {
         array[r][c]=c+"";//your calue
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could Use JSON array parser to do the job,Example

```
   JSONObject mainObj = new JSONOBject(myString);
if(mainObj != null){
    JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("prodCat_list");
    if(list != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length();i++){
            JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);
            if(elem != null){
                JSONArray prods = elem.getJSONArray("prods");
                if(prods != null){
                    for(int j = 0; j < prods.length();j++){
                        JSONObject innerElem = prods.getJSONObject(j);
                        if(innerElem != null){
                            int cat_id = innerELem.getInt("cat_id");
                            int pos = innerElem.getInt("position");
                            String sku = innerElem.getString("sku");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```